# PHP create files with wrong permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a php files, name `image_creat.php`

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from images where key!='en' Order By id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$imageurl =  dirname(__FILE__) . '/../images/';
$width = $row['width'];
$height = $row['height'];
$source_image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($row['image']);
$desired_width = '800';
$desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
$virtual_image = @imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
@imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
@imagejpeg($virtual_image,$imageurl,'100');
}
```

I use SSH to setting the permission for it:

```
chmod 0755 /var/www/html/php/image_creat.php
chown root:root /var/www/html/php/image_creat.php
```

Then also setting permission for the images folder:

```
chmod 0755 /var/www/html/php/images/
```

But after the php script create `jpeg` files, I find all the files with permission of `644`, so that my browser refused to visit it. where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l` for both the images folder and some of its contents? We need to know the owner user and group.

Comment: 644 should be readable as well...

Comment: You might be able to use chmod directly in your script `chmod("path/to/image.jpeg", 0755);` As for the why - the user your php scripts run as is determined by the web server (e.g apache with mod_php will usually be apache or www-data; php-fpm will be based on the pool, etc) - this determines the owner, and the umask of that user determined the permissions of newly created files. That said, 644 should be readable (although, some setups do require execute permissions on php files, they shouldn't be needed on images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I find all the files with permission of 644, so that my browser refused to visit it

Then either you're not telling us the whole story or your facts are mis-reported.

644 means -rw-r--r-- and since the creating script is only executable for root, the output ile will be owned by root. The file is readable by all users (including the webserver uid).

I suggest you go read up on Unix file permissions.

There might be lots of reasons why the file is not readable by the webserver uid - top of the list would be directory permissions (but if *all* the dirs above are 0755 - drwxr-xr-x - then that's not the cause) and ACLs.

BTW using the root account for routine data maintenance is a very bad idea.